# What is the minimum number of steps to get from (a, b) to (0, 0) if you can either double one number or add or subtract any number from both numbers?

Tags: arrays, math, logic

Assume to be the worst case scenario. Adding any number (can be negative) but has to be to both numbers. Only one can be doubled from (a, b). This can be done as many times as desired.

What is the minimum steps to get to (0, 0)?

Comment: Is it clear that reaching `(0,0)` from `(a,b)` is always possible (using the described operations) in the first place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I've tagged it thusly. Maths, logic. They're acceptable on this Q&A board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can always be done in three steps.

First step: Add a number `x`, such that the one number is twice as big as the other number:

```
 a + x = 2 (b + x)
a - 2b = x
```

Then double the second number (which makes both numbers equal) and finally subtract everything (making it `(0, 0)`).

You can save steps if both numbers are already zero (0 steps), both numbers are equal (1 step) or `x` is zero (two steps).